# How to convert rows into columns in SQL based on column field in SQL

Tags: sql, string, pivot

[image]

Hi,

I am having this requirement to create an extract with alias name for a given ID.
Alias has been entered as rows in the table. But, the requirement is to add that to different column and create one single row for an ID as described. Need to achieve this is SQL. Pivot option didn't work

Comment: Which database are you using, what kind of query did you try to use and you also shouldn't provide data as an image.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
    max(case when not is_alias then firstname end) firstname,
    max(case when not is_alias then lastname  end) lastname,
    max(case when is_alias and rn = 1 then firstname || ' ' || lastname end) alias1,
    max(case when is_alias and rn = 2 then firstname || ' ' || lastname end) alias2,
    max(case when is_alias and rn = 3 then firstname || ' ' || lastname end) alias3
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id, is_alias order by ??) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id
```

Notes:

- for the columns to be consistently orderd, you need a column that defines the ordering of the aliases; I represented it as `??` in the query
- if you want to handle more than three possible aliases per `id`, you can add more conditional expressions to the `select` clause
- you did not tell which database you are running; this uses a standard that is portable as possible, but:

  - I used standard ANSI string concatenation operator `||`; not all database support that
  - I treated `is_alias` as a legitimate boolean value, that can be used in conditional expressions; this might need to be adapted too

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is to pivot your table. This general idea might help you:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
    FROM TABLE1
) AS ORG_TABLE PIVOT(<the operation you want done>[VAR] FOR <VAR> IN 

(<List of values>) 

AS PivotTable
```